# Save data frame as csv/text file in pandas without line numbering

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a data frame using a text file in pandas.

```
df = pd.read_table('inputfile.txt',names=['Line'])
```

when I do `df`

```
Line
0   17/08/31 13:24:48 INFO spark.SparkContext: Run...
1   17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: ...
2   17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: ...
3   17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: ...
4   17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO util.Utils: Successfull...
5   17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4...
6   17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO Remoting: Starting remo...
7   17/08/31 13:24:50 INFO Remoting: Remoting star...
8   17/08/31 13:24:50 INFO Remoting: Remoting now ...
9   17/08/31 13:24:50 INFO util.Utils: Successfull...
```

Now I want to save this file as `csv`

```
df.to_csv('outputfile')
```

The result I get is this

```
0,17/08/31 13:24:48 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
1,17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: user1
2,17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: user1
3,17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(user1);
4,17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 17101.
5,17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
6,17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
7,17/08/31 13:24:50 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :
8,17/08/31 13:24:50 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: 
9,17/08/31 13:24:50 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 100033.
```

I want my output to be

```
17/08/31 13:24:48 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: user1
17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: user1
17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(user1);
17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 17101.
17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
17/08/31 13:24:49 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
17/08/31 13:24:50 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :
17/08/31 13:24:50 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: 
17/08/31 13:24:50 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 100033.
```

I have tried a couple of methods like below but still getting the same result not my desired output.

```
np.savetxt(r'np.txt', df.Line, fmt='%d')

df.to_csv(sep=' ', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: What does `df.columns` give?

Comment: @james It gives Line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the number might be part of the string in the `Line` column.  You can replace the leading digits and spaces with nothing and output it to a file with no index using:

```
df.Line.str.replace('^\d+ +','').to_csv('outputfile.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: I am still getting the numbering in front of each line

Answer (score 8):

James' answer is likely correct given the special case.
However, there's the standard behaviour of `pandas` to put the line number as a column without header in front.
To remove this, simply set the `index=` argument to `False`:

```
df.to_csv("outfile.csv", index=False)
```

(Edit: Corrected, according to what @Haagimus correctly pointed out to no mislead anyone here.)

Answer (score 3):

Christian was almost right. If you look at the docs for the [to_csv command](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv).

According to the docs

`index : boolean, default True,  Write row names (index)`

I highly recommend the assistant tool Kite for helping with simple things like this.

```
df.to_csv('outfile.csv', index=False)
```